# Infinite amount of flags

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

I have been going through some old posts, flagging them as necessary. But I have noticed that the number of posts that I am able to flag is continually staying at ten. It seems that the new flagging system has messed this up.

[image: 10 flags]

I am able to keep flagging posts even after 10, so I know it isn't a UI bug. This is a very big problem, because I can flag infinitely many times. And I am pretty sure this isn't the intended behavior of the overlords

### This isn't because I am being awarded more flags. I flag more than 13 posts in 5 minutes, and I can keep going without restriction

---

Some of the flags were accepted, so now my number is up to 13. But it is still staying at 13

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this. Flagging your question resulted in 9 remaining flags.

Comment: Big question is can you keep flagging more than 10 (i.e. quite critical bug) or you get blocked and just see 10 flags remaining meaning just UI bug?

Comment: Also, have you noticed this multiple times? Flagging correctly can increase the number of flags you get per day, so that could make it look like you're not using up flags.

Comment: -1 just for the lazy, soulless black ellipses. Every self-respecting bug report needs [red freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/192187).

Comment: maybe its related to [Number of flags remaining increased](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184683/number-of-flags-remaining-increased)

Comment: Maybe the flags are silently ignored. Can you check your flagging history? Maybe post screenshot from there?

Comment: maybe useful flags wont be counted or maybe you are getting extra flags for useful flags.

Comment: It seems like this is resolved, so shouldn't it be status completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems as though it has been unintentionally solved thanks to all of the changes with flags

Now I am once again a mere mortal of flagging, who must wait till the day's end to go on the hunt for bad posts again.

[On the recent changes to flagging and limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits)

Comment: Oh, shoot - I forgot to circle back on this. There was a period of time between the initial rollout of the flag changes and now where *close* flags were unlimited - thanks for reporting it!